# combination of unit step functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I might be completely over thinking, or over looking this, but I am having a hard time understanding the linear combinations of step functions.

Example: $g(t) = u_{1}(t) + 2u_{3}(t) - 6u_{4}(t)$

I understand the concept of a single unit step function, for example, 
$$ 6u_{4}(t) =\begin{cases}0, & t  <  4\\6, & t  \geq 4 \end{cases} $$

So, my question is, how do I combine these types of functions?

**EDIT**
Going off of Alan's answer, and my example above:

$$g(t) = \begin{cases}0, & t  <  1\\1, & 1 \leq t  < 3\\ 3, & 3 \leq t < 4\\ -3, & t\geq4\end{cases} $$ .. is this correct?

Comment: (Yes it is right!) Intuitive : start at height $0$ ; at point $t=1$ go one step higher, at point $t=3$ go $2$ units higher, at point $t=4$ go $6$ units lower.

Comment: Ah! That helped me from a graphing standpoint. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of functions is defined pointwise. For example, say you have two step functions

$u_1(t) = \begin{cases} 0, & t < 1 \\ 1, & t \ge 1 \end{cases}$

and

$u_2(t) = \begin{cases} 0, & t < 2 \\ 1, & t \ge 2 \end{cases}$.

Then a linear combination of them, say $au_1(t) + bu_2(t)$ would be

$au_1(t) + bu_2(t) = \begin{cases} 0, & t < 1 \\ a, & 1 \le t < 2 \\ a+b, & t \ge 2 \end{cases}$.

Comment: Alan, thanks for your answer. I've updated my question. I believe I understand it now, but please correct me if I'm wrong.